# How to calculate the Fourier transform of Sinc[b (ω1 - ω2)]?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would  like to calculate the Fourier transform of  Sinc[ b (ω1 - ω2)], but there are some problems as follows:

---

**My target is**

$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\text{Sinc}(b (\text{$\omega_1$}-\text{$\omega_2$})) e^{-i \text{$ \omega_1 t_1$}  } e^{-i  \text{$ \omega_2 t_2 $} } d \text{$\omega_1$} d\text{$\omega_2$}   =\frac{2 \pi ^2}{b} \Pi \left(\frac{\text{$t_1$}}{2 b}\right) \delta (\text{$t_1$}+\text{$t_2$})$

---

**The problem is as follow:**

I use the following code

```
    Assuming[{b >0 }, FourierTransform[  Sinc[b (ω1 - ω2)], {ω1, ω2}, {t1, t2}, \!\(TraditionalForm\`FourierParameters -> {1, \(-1\)}\)]]
```

After runing the above code for a long time, the out put is

```
    (I \[Pi] DiracDelta[t1+t2] (-Log[I b-I t1]+Log[-I b+I t1]+Log[-I (b+t1)]-Log[I (b+t1)]))/b
```

It can be further simplified to be 0, because

```
    Log[-I (b - t1)] + Log[-I (b + t1)] - Log[I (b - t1)] - Log[I (b + t1)]

    = Log[I (b - t1)*I (b + t1)] - Log[I (b - t1)*I (b + t1)]

    = Log[-b^2 + t1^2] - Log[-b^2 + t1^2]

    = 0
```

This means 
$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\text{Sinc}(b (\text{$\omega_1$}-\text{$\omega_2$})) e^{-i \text{$ \omega_1 t_1$}  } e^{-i  \text{$ \omega_2 t_2 $} } d \text{$t_1$} d\text{$t_2$}   =0$ ??

How to solve this porblem?

---

***Clue 1: $Sinc[ω1 - ω2]$***

```
    FourierTransform[ Sinc[ω1 - ω2], {ω1, ω2}, {t1,   t2}, \!\(TraditionalForm\`FourierParameters -> {1, \(-1\)}\)]
```

The result is $ π^2 DiracDelta[t1 + t2] (Sign[1 - t1] + Sign[1 + t1]) $.

But in Mathematica, `(Sign[1 - t1] + Sign[1 + t1])`  does not equal to   `2 UnitBox[t1/2]`,  because   `FullSimplify[Sign[1 - t1] + Sign[1 + t1] - 2 UnitBox[t1/2]] = Piecewise[{{-1, t1 == -1 || t1 == 1}}, 0]`

---

***Clue 2: $Sinc[b ω]$***

```
    FourierTransform[ Sinc[b ω], {ω}, {t}, \!\(TraditionalForm\`FourierParameters -> {1, \(-1\)}\)]
```

The result is  $ \frac{\pi}{2 b} (Sign[b - t] + Sign[b + t])$.

---

***Clue 3:  $Sinc[3 (ω1 - ω2)]$***

```
    Assuming[{a > b },  FourierTransform[Sinc[3 (ω1 - ω2)], {ω1, ω2}, {t1, t2}, \!\(TraditionalForm\`FourierParameters -> {1, \(-1\)}\)]]
```

The result is  0.

---

Any comment or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please include actual code (that can be copy-and-pasted) rather than just images thereof.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, thank you for the comment. I have added the actual code and delete the image.

Comment: Actually, FullSimplify[Sign[1 - t1] + Sign[1 + t1] - 2 UnitBox[t1/2], 
 Assumptions -> t2 > t1 > 1] simplifies to zero. Your clue #1 is incorrect.

Comment: @ bill s , Thank you for the comment. But I think  clue #1 is correct, because without any assumption, the result is not zero,  i.e., FullSimplify[Sign[1 - t1] + Sign[1 + t1] - 2 UnitBox[t1/2]]   simplifies to  Piecewise[{{-1, t1 == -1 || t1 == 1}}, 0]. Generally speaking, t1 is a real number, and the assumption of t1>1 is not true.

Comment: I agree with @bills, but for a different reason: The [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) $\Pi(t)$ does not equal `UnitBox[t]`; rather, it is equal to `1/2 (Sign[1 - 2 t] + Sign[1 + 2 t])`.  Examine `UnitBox[t/2]` at `t = ±1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Thank you for the helpful comment. But what is the ''function name''  for rectangular function in Mathematica?

Comment: I don't believe there is one, which is why we get `FourierTransform[Sinc[(\[Omega]1)], {\[Omega]1}, {t}]` in terms of `Sign`.  I suppose `HeavisidePi` is meant to be the function, but it is undefined at the discontinuity rather than being defined to be `1/2`.

Comment: In applying the logarithm laws is it possible some branch cut discontinuities were removed? If so, they could account for the sign function part of the expected result.

Comment: @Michael E2 thank you for the comment.  I aggree with you.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, thank you. I aggree with you.

Comment: Your integration variables in the "target" $\LaTeX$ expression should be $d\omega_1d\omega_2$, not $dt_1dt_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem, we can relate *multiple integrals* to *iterated integrals*, i.e.
$$\int f(x,y) dxdy=\int\left(\int f(x,y)dx\right)dy$$
 as long as the integrand is sufficiently convergent. I am not sure if this is the case at hand, but I will assume it nonetheless.

In practise, this means that we can replace `FourierTransform[f[a,b],{a,b},{x,y}]` with `FourierTransform[FourierTransform[f[a,b],a,x],b,y]`. To simplify the calculations further, I will insert a `FullSimplify` between the `FourierTransform`s so that the calculation is faster and simpler.

> `Timing[
>   FourierTransform[
>   FullSimplify[
>   FourierTransform[Sinc[a( x-y)],x,t,FourierParameters->{1,-1}]
>   ,{t,y,a}\[Element]Reals
>   ],y,s,FourierParameters->{1,-1}
>   ]
>   ]`

yields

> `{0.039023,(\[Pi]^2 DiracDelta[s+t] (Sign[a-t]+Sign[a+t]))/a}`

on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple and smart answer. This is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Still not a full answer, but maybe pointing towards the solution.

```
PiecewiseExpand[
 FourierTransform[
  Sinc[ω1 - ω2], 
  {ω1, ω2}, {t1, t2}, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}
  ],
 t1 ∈ Reals
 ]
```

[image]

This does not work with `Sinc[b (ω1 - ω2)]`, though and I don't know why. It should only be a matter of the transformation formula, but apparently, *Mathematica* is not clever enough to apply it automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I aggree with you that Mathematica is not clever enough to sovle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem becomes simpler when you do a unitary variable substitution:

$$
s = \frac{t_1+t_2}{\sqrt{2}} \qquad \sigma = \frac{t_1-t_2}{\sqrt{2}}\\
x = \frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{\sqrt{2}} \qquad y = \frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{\sqrt{2}}\\
$$

The double Fourier integral then separates into two easy ones:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{sinc}[b(\omega_1-\omega_2)]e^{-i\omega_1t_1}e^{-i\omega_2t_2}d\omega_1d\omega_2
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{sinc}(\sqrt{2}by)e^{-isx}e^{-ity}dx\,dy\\
= \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-isx} dx\right)
\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sinc}(\sqrt{2}by)e^{-ity}dy\right)
$$

These we can do with *Mathematica*:

```
Sqrt[2π]*InverseFourierTransform[1, x, s]
(* 2π*DiracDelta[s] *)

Sqrt[2π]*InverseFourierTransform[Sinc[Sqrt[2]*b*y], y, t] // Simplify

(* π*(Sign[Sqrt[2]*b-t] + Sign[Sqrt[2]*b+t])/(2*Sqrt[2]*b) *)
```

Hence the result is

$$
2\pi\delta(s) \cdot
\frac{\pi[\text{sign}(\sqrt{2}b-t)+\text{sign}(\sqrt{2}b+t)]}{2\sqrt{2}b}\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{2}b}\delta\left(\frac{t_1+t_2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left[\text{sign}\left(\sqrt{2}b-\frac{t_1-t_2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{sign}\left(\sqrt{2}b+\frac{t_1-t_2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{b}\delta(t_1+t_2)\left[\text{sign}\left(b-\frac{t_1-t_2}{2}\right)+\text{sign}\left(b+\frac{t_1-t_2}{2}\right)\right]\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{b}\delta(t_1+t_2)\left[\text{sign}(b-t_1)+\text{sign}(b+t_1)\right]
$$

where the last step uses the $\delta$-function to constrain $t_2=-t_1$ and thus to simplify the $\text{sign}$-functions' arguments with $\frac{t_1-t_2}{2}=t_1$.

If you're not too picky about the boundaries where $t_1=\pm b$, then the second half can be written as twice the `UnitBox` function $\Pi$:

$$
\ldots = \frac{2\pi^2}{b}\delta(t_1+t_2)\cdot \Pi\left(\frac{t_1}{2b}\right)
$$

This confirms your target solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.  I am not sure whether this answer (with a symmetric UnitBox function) is the same as my traget equation  (with an asymmetric UnitBox function). Maybe both equations are correct？

Comment: Yes you're right. I've edited the derivation to arrive at your target solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the previous result as $f$ and using `Simplify` we can obtain

```
f = π/b I DiracDelta[t1 + t2] 
     (-Log[I b - I t1] + Log[-I b + I t1] + Log[-I (b + t1)] - Log[I (b + t1)]);
Simplify[f, Assumptions -> 0 < b < t1]
Simplify[f, Assumptions -> -b < t1 < b]
Simplify[f, Assumptions -> t1 < -b < 0]

(*
    0
    (2 π^2 DiracDelta[t1 + t2])/b
    0
*)
```

However, we get another factor of 2 when we evaluate

```
FourierTransform[ Sinc[b (ω1 - ω2)], {ω1, ω2}, {t1, t2},
 FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> -b < t1 < b]


(*   (4 π^2 DiracDelta[t1 + t2])/b   *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.